# Conservar el valor obtenido del servidor (node js ) en una variable (javascript) que se utilizará en todo el sistema

Tags: javascript, html5, nodejs, express

Al validar el usuario y contraseña obtenemos los datos del usuario y empresa, todo bien desde la ruta inicial.

Eje. ruta inicial (index.js)

```
router.get('/', authController.isAuthenticated, (req, res)=>{
  async function renderIndex() {
      const usuarioX= req.user
      //console.log('nUsuario: '+usuarioX.nUsuario+' idUsuario: '+usuarioX.idUsuario+' nombre:'+usuarioX.nombre+' '+usuarioX.apellidoP)
      const [empresaX] = await empresaController.readAll1()
      res.render('index', {empresaActual:empresaX, usuarioActual:usuarioX})    //{empresa:empresaX}   
  }
  renderIndex()
})
```

eje. datos mostrados en el partials ('../partials/barraDatosSistema.ejs')

```
    <div id="Bienvenido" class="classBarDatSistItems"> 
            <!-- <input id="usuarioNomApellidoP" type="text" value="Bienvenido (a): " disabled=true> -->
            <input id="usuarioNomApellidoP" type="text" value="Bienvenido (a): <% if (usuarioActual) { %> <%= usuarioActual.nombre %> <%= usuarioActual.apellidoP %> <% } %> " disabled=true>
    </div>    
    <div id="empresa" class="classBarDatSistItems">
        <!-- <input id="nomComercial" type="text" value=" " disabled=true> -->
        <input id="empresaActualX" type="text" value="<% if (empresaActual) { %> <%= empresaActual.nomComercial %> <% } %>" hidden>
        <input id="nomComercial" type="text" value="  " disabled="true" >
    </div>
```

Problema: Al cambiar de ruta ya no muestra los datos del usuario y empresa (necesarios en otras pantallas).

eje. ruta usuarios (usuarios.js)

```
// Rutas para renderizar
router.get('/create', (req, res)=>{  
    res.render(usuarios')
})
```

Solución: copiar el proceso de la ruta incial a todas las rutas de las pantallas.. (no creo sea lo correcto repetir el código).

He intentado en una función (muestraEmpresaActual) que se llama en el evento onload del body.

```
    <body onload="mueveReloj(); muestraEmpresaActual()">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <%- include('../partials/header.ejs') %>  
            <%- include('../partials/barraDatosSistema.ejs') %>  
            <%- include('../partials/nav.ejs') %>  
            <%- include('../partials/aside.ejs') %>  
            <%- include('../partials/main.ejs') %>
            <%- include('../partials/footer.ejs') %> 
            <!-- <%- include('../partials/disenadoPor.ejs') %>-->
        </div>
    </body>
```

eje. script

```
//const nUsuario = "1"
//const idUsuario = "Admin"
//const usuarioNomApellidoP = "Nombre Apellido"
const versionSistema = 'v1.1.202201r01'                               
//const nomComercial =   'Datos emrpesa'
const fechaActual = day + "/" + month + "/" + year      
//const horaActual = '00:00:00 am'

//document.getElementById("horaActual").value = horaActual
document.getElementById("fechaActual").value = fechaActual
//document.getElementById("nomComercial").value = nomComercial
document.getElementById("versionSistema").value = versionSistema
//document.getElementById("usuarioNomApellidoP").value = usuarioNomApellidoP
//document.getElementById("idUsuario").value = idUsuario
//document.getElementById("nUsuario").value = nUsuario

function muestraEmpresaActual(){ 
    let vempresaActualX = document.getElementById("empresaActualX").value
    let vempresaActual = ''

    //console.log('engineMain-Empresa actual: '+vempresaActualX)
    //cadenaTrim = vempresaActualX.trim()
    //console.log('catacteres: '+cadenaTrim.length)
    
    if (cadenaTrim.length > 0) {
        document.getElementById("nomComercial").value = 'empactX'+vempresaActualX
        vempresaActual = vempresaActualX
    } else {
        document.getElementById("nomComercial").value = vempresaActual
    }
}
```

Sigo indagando...

Saludos.

Intente ahora con localStorage y trabaja bien....

```
function muestraEmpresaActual(){ 
    // Activando y configurando localStorage para la empresa actual: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hb8O0qRqiSk
    //let storageDatosInicio = window.sessionStorage
    let storageDatosInicio = window.localStorage
    let datosEnLocalStorage = storageDatosInicio.length
    console.log('datos en el localstorage: '+datosEnLocalStorage)


    // Obteniendo datos enviados desde el BakEnd... y capturados en el HTML...
    let usuarioNumBack = document.getElementById("usuarioNumX").value
    let usuarioIDBack = document.getElementById("usuarioIDX").value
    let usuarioNombreBack = document.getElementById("usuarioNombreX").value

    let empresaNumBack = document.getElementById("empresaNumX").value
    let empresaRazonSocialBack = document.getElementById("empresaRazonSocialX").value
    let empresaNomComercialBack = document.getElementById("empresaMomComercialX").value

    cadenaTrim = empresaNomComercialBack.trim()

    if (cadenaTrim.length > 0) {                        // Validando si tiene dato desde el BackEnd
        if ( datosEnLocalStorage == 0 ) {            // Validando si el storageDatosInicio tiene datos... si no, entonces asigna... 

            storageDatosInicio.setItem('usuarioNum', `${usuarioNumBack}`)
            storageDatosInicio.setItem('usuarioID', `${usuarioIDBack}`)
            storageDatosInicio.setItem('usuarioNombre', `${usuarioNombreBack}`)
            
            storageDatosInicio.setItem('empresaNum', `${empresaNumBack}`)
            storageDatosInicio.setItem('empresaRazonSocial', `${empresaRazonSocialBack}`)
            storageDatosInicio.setItem('empresaNomComercial', `${empresaNomComercialBack}`)

            console.log('SI registra datos en el storageDatosInicio')
        }else { 
            console.log('NO registra datos en el storageDatosInicio')
        }
    } 
    document.getElementById("usuarioNomApellidoP").value = storageDatosInicio.getItem('usuarioNombre')
    document.getElementById("nomComercial").value = storageDatosInicio.getItem('empresaNomComercial')
}
```

Pero.. tengo duda cual utilizar localStorage o sesionStorage... porque me salgo de la aplicación y siguen los datos en el localStorage..

Si tienen algún comentario para mejorar... ... gracias... solo voy a invocar una función para que limpie el storage..

storageDatosInicio.clear()

Saludos.

Comment: Estás en lo cierto, repetir código debe evitarse. Por otro lado, existen muchas opciones de lograr lo que te propones: cookies, localstorage, interceptors, atributos data-*, etc. En cuanto a tu pregunta, ¿cuál es la duda? Tal parece que pides opiniones o sugerencias para lograr tu propósito. Las preguntas basadas en opiniones terminan cerradas. Saludos

Comment: Por cierto, ¿qué tiene que ver la etiqueta de Java con tu pregunta? Java no es igual a Javascript, aunque por una desafortunada circunstancia ambos tienen la palabra Java en el nombre. ;)

Comment: Mi pregunta es como conservar el valor obtenido desde el servidor y poder utilizarlo en las demás rutas de la aplicación?

(En cuanto a java... es un error de dedo.. no entiendo muy bien este sitio... )

Comment: Tu pregunta es justamente el clásico dilema del Server Side Rendering. Por eso lo común es que el servidor solo se encargue del renderizado la primera vez que el usuario accede al sitio y a partir de ahí usar un framework como React que se encargue del renderizado del lado del cliente. Es la unica forma de evitar estar mandando los mismos datos una y otra vez.

Comment: _"tengo duda cual utilizar localStorage o sesionStorage... porque me salgo de la aplicación y siguen los datos en el localStorage"_ ¿Cuál te conviene más a ti? ¿Quieres que la información persista cuando se cierre el navegador o que se elimine al cerrarlo? Eso ya dependerá de cómo funciona tu aplicación. Si no quieres que cuando te salgas sigan los datos del usuario usa sesionStorage. Si quieres guardar información  y que persista, como el idioma seleccionado o el tema, usa localStorage.

Comment: Si.. lo que necesito es que al cerrar el navegador se elimine, entonces será con sesionStorage.. es lo mejor...